# Resgatar ID em modal de retorno Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

já procurei bastante mais não consegui nada parecido. Tenho um cadastro que retorna lastInsertId() e esse cadastro é feito com Ajax. No success (Ajax) depois de concluir o cadastro abre uma modal. Precisava passar esse ultimo id inserido para a modal como variável (tipo quando é passado por $_GET) para poder comparar com os dados do banco..
Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço...

Comment: Poste seu código

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: 'models/createPedido.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (retorno) {
                $('input[name="termosPedidoId"]').val(retorno);
                modal.modal('show');
            }
        });

Comment: Envie o retorno do Ajax para a modal. Simples.

Comment: É bom incluir na pergunta todas as informações relevantes, não nos comentários.

Comment: Como o nome diz, "comentários" são para fazer comentários, tirar dúvidas pontuais etc..

Comment: Foi mal...é minha segunda duvida que posto aqui. O retorno do Ajax consigo enviar para a modal, mas como comparar esse valor com a consulta do banco.

Comment: Coloque todas as suas dúvidas na pergunta clicando no link Editar.

Answer (score 0):

**Bibliotecas e Script**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  // tudo que estiver aqui poderá ser executado, após o documento ser carregado

  $( "#submitBtn" ).click(function(e) {

    // está função diz, que quando esse formulario for enviado, tudo oque estiver aqui será executado.
    e.preventDefault(); // está função é usada pro form não ir para outra pagina, pois o evento padrão de um formulario é ir para outra pagina.
    var data = $("#form").serialize(); // a function serialize serve para pegar todos os valores que foram colocados nos inputs do form
    $.ajax({
      // está é a função ajax, do jquery, ela será usada para fazer a requisição assícrona.
      url: "models/createPedido.php", // aqui vai a url da requisição
      data:  data, // aqui vai os dados para o servidor, geralmente são os inputs do form
      method: "POST", // aqui vai o método da requisição, acho que você já sabe sobre o get e post !
      dataType: "json", // aqui será o tipo de resposta que vamos receber, será no formato json, um formato simples e mais usado.
      success: function(data){
        // essa é a function success, ela ira ser executada se a requisição for feita com sucesso
        $("#recebe").val(data); // aqui estamos setando o valor retornado do php, no input
         // a variavel data, veio do parametro da function, e será a resposta do php.
         $("#myModal").modal('show');
      },
      error: function(){
        // essa é funcion error, ela será executada caso ocorrer algum erro na requisição
        $("#myModalErro").modal('show');
      }
    });
  });

});

</script>
```

**HTML** - formulário e modais

```
<form>
    ......................
    ......................
    <button name="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>                
</form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sucesso </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>ID</p>
                 <form action="Pagina_Destino.php" method="post">
                <input name='recebe' id="recebe" value="QUERO_PASSAR_O_ID_AQUI">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light" ><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-send">Enviar</i></span> </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModalErro" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Erro </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Erro na requisição</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Pagina createPedido.php**

```
<?php
  // recebe os dados
  $zzz = $_POST["zzz"];
   ...................
   ...................

  //scripts para obtenção do lastInsertId
  ....................


  //(MySQLi OO)
  $valorlastInsertId = $conn->insert_id;

  //(MySQLi Procedural)
  $valorlastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

  //(PDO)
  $valorlastInsertId = $conn->lastInsertId();


  //vai ser o value do input name='recebe' id="recebe" na function success do modal id="myModal"

  echo json_encode($valorlastInsertId);
?>
```